# Search strings behind an index

Tags: python-2.7

I work with a list (`lst_data`) containing paths to the data.

Here's an example from my list

```
lst_data = ["SDE_AGS_ADM.PLUVIOMETRIE \ SDE_AGS_ADM.Pluviometres_DAVAR",
            "SDE_AGS_ADM.AIRE_PROTEGE_GOUV \ SDE_AGS_ADM.reserves_integrales_R",
            "SDE_AGS_ADM.DGRSC_Lignes_feu"]
```

Let's look at this list.

The first element contains 2 ".", the second element also contains 2 ".", but the third element contains only one ".".

I try to get the characters after the last "." each element of the list.

Can anyone help me?

I already try using the `count ()` function. But I'm confused :-)

thank you

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data after the **last** period `.`, use [**`str.split()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and take the last element of the returned list:

```
lst_data = ["SDE_AGS_ADM.PLUVIOMETRIE \ SDE_AGS_ADM.Pluviometres_DAVAR",
            "SDE_AGS_ADM.AIRE_PROTEGE_GOUV \ SDE_AGS_ADM.reserves_integrales_R",
            "SDE_AGS_ADM.DGRSC_Lignes_feu"]
new = [item.split('.')[-1] for item in lst_data]
```

---

```
>>> lst_data = ["SDE_AGS_ADM.PLUVIOMETRIE \ SDE_AGS_ADM.Pluviometres_DAVAR",
...             "SDE_AGS_ADM.AIRE_PROTEGE_GOUV \ SDE_AGS_ADM.reserves_integrales_R",
...             "SDE_AGS_ADM.DGRSC_Lignes_feu"]
>>> new = [item.split('.')[-1] for item in lst_data]
>>> new
['Pluviometres_DAVAR', 'reserves_integrales_R', 'DGRSC_Lignes_feu']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).  It returns an array of strings delimited by a pattern from a base string.  The second piece to this puzzle is referring to the last element of an array: arr[-1] does the trick.  Your code would look something like this:

```
 list = ["i.want.pie","i.want.icecream","i.want.thirdthing"]
 listofwhatiwant = [x.split(".")[-1] for x in list]
```

listofwhatiwant now has "pie", "icecream", and "thirdthing" in it.

See running example [here](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user39_fLswTJlgSLwLDyQ.py).